# Prove the existence of homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

I am trying to answer the following question. Is there any group homomorphsim $\phi: D_4 \rightarrow S_5$?

Comment: (i) Is there a homomorphsim $D_4 \to S_4$? (ii) Is there a homomorphsim $S_4 \to S_5$?

Comment: Given any two groups there's always a homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$. It might not be a  very interesting homomorphism though.

Comment: I mean a non-trivial homomorphism...

Answer (score 0):

The subgroup $\{e, (12)(34), (13), (13)(24), (14)(23), (24), (1234), (1432)\}$ of $S_4$ is isomorphic to $D_4$. Hence we have injective group homomorphisms
$$
D_4\hookrightarrow S_4\hookrightarrow S_5. 
$$
Actually, all three Sylow-2-subgroups of $S_4$ are isomorphic to $D_4$.

Comment: Perfect. But I see that there is a recipe to define a homomorphism $:D_n \rightarrow S_n$, for instance $\phi (\tau) =(1 2 3 4), \phi(\sigma)=(2 4)$. But is really enough to check that $\phi(\sigma \tau) =\phi (\tau^{-1} \sigma),$ to obtain the result?

Comment: You just have to show that $(1234)$ and $(24)$ generated $D_4$. A homomorphism is determined by the images of the generators.